# What difference does it make if i add both versions of my website to google webmaster tools one is with 'www' and another is without 'www'

Tags: seo, google-search-console, url

What is the exact difference between website `with www` and `without www` and how does google counts on it.

I have added my website in `google webmaster tools` and verified it successfully `with www`, now the problem is that i am confused whether i should add another version of my website that is `without www`?

If yes, what should be the format of URL? Should i include http or not in both the versions. Below is the image of how google asks to enter url.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

to avoid duplicated content problem, related to availability of your site with two addresses (www + non-www) simultaneously,  you should redirect one version to another (301 redirect www to non-www or vise versa).

adding of two versions to search console will only help you to take care, that nobody comes to the site version, which you redirect. If somebody comes, then you will know - your redirect doesn't work.

Comment: Okay so i should add a 301 redirect to `without www` in my case. And add another property in search console for monitoring purpose? Am i right.?

Comment: yes. after you set a redirect, be aware, that you always use the site url without redirect for linking purposes, so if your site will be linked by other they don't link to redirected address. The webmaster tools property, which is set up for redirected url should always show zero.